# activar animacion al hacer scroll hacia abajo o hacia arriba con intersection observer

Tags: javascript, html5, animación

la siguiente animacion solo se activa al hacer scroll hacia abajo cuando aparece en el viewport no sé como hacer para cuando se hace scroll hacia arriba vuelva a ejecutarse. estoy utilizando intersection observer API.

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center">text and icons animation</h1>
  <H1 class="text-center">SCROLL DOWN >>>>>>></H1>
<div class="space">
</div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1 class="text-animation animatable revealOnScroll">2 great value superfast fibre broadband deals</h1>
    <p  class="text-animation animatable revealOnScroll">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A doloremque quam dicta aperiam hic ab est tempora pariatur harum placeat, corrupti et! Incidunt, nemo perferendis delectus autem alias voluptas cupiditate.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <div class="content">
        <div class="list-icons">
           <i  class="fa fa-arrow-down icon-size  animatable revealOnScroll" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="info-icon">
          <h4 class="revealOnScroll text-animation-2 animatable">explore</h4>
          <p class="revealOnScroll text-animation-2 animatable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, consequuntur facere. Quidem nihil fugit corrupti incidunt
        </p>
        </div>

      </div>
       <div class="content">
        <div class="list-icons">
           <i  class="fa  fa-database icon-size  animatable revealOnScroll" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="info-icon">
          <h4 class="revealOnScroll text-animation-2 animatable">discover</h4>
         <p class="revealOnScroll text-animation-2 animatable">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, consequuntur facere. Quidem nihil fugit corrupti incidunt</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="list-icons">
           <i  class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle icon-size  animatable revealOnScroll" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="info-icon">
          <h4 class="revealOnScroll text-animation-2 animatable">researching</h4>
           <p class="revealOnScroll text-animation-2 animatable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, consequuntur facere. Quidem nihil fugit corrupti incidunt</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="intersection">

        <div class="box animatable"></div>
        <div class="box animatable"></div>
        <div class="box animatable"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
 <div class="space">
</div>   
</div>



body
{
  background-color: #000;
}

h1,
h4
{
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff;
}
p,li
{
  color:grey;
}

i
{
  color:blue;
}
.space
{
  height:1500px;
}


.text-animation
{
  max-width:360px;
}


.animatable {

  /* initially hide animatable objects */
  visibility: hidden;

  /* initially pause animatable objects their animations */
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;   
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;     
  -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;   
  animation-play-state: paused; 
}



/* show objects being animated */
.animated {
  visibility: visible;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -o-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;

  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running;
  -ms-animation-play-state: running;
  -o-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;




}


@-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal {
   from {
      left: -800px;
   }

   to {
      left: 10px;
   }
}   

.text-animation {
   -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
 /*  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;*/
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;/*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */

   position: relative;
   padding: 2px;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal-2 {
   from {
      right: -200px;
   }

   to {
      right: 10px;
   }
}   


.text-animation-2 {
   -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal-2;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
 /*  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;*/
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;/*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */

   position: relative;
   padding: 2px;
} 


ul
{
  list-style: none;

}



/* increase size fontawesome icons with keyframes*/

@-webkit-keyframes size-icons {
   0% {
      font-size: 0;
   }

   100% {
      font-size: 3.5em;
   }
}   


.icon-size{
   -webkit-animation-name: size-icons;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
   /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1 ;*/
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;/*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */

} 



.content
{
  position: relative;
margin-bottom: 80px;

}

.list-icons
{
  padding-right:60px;

  position:relative;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
}

.info-icon
{
  padding-left:100px;
  margin-top:-70px;
  position:relative;

}


/***intersection example css**/
:root {
    --base: #202050;
    --border: #ccc;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.box {
    width: 30vh;
    height: 30vh;
    margin: 20vh 0;
    border: 0.2rem solid var(--border);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background 0.8s ease,
        border 0.4s ease;
}

.box.isVisible {
    border-color: var(--base);
    background-color: var(--base);
}

.box.isNotVisible
{
  border-color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes size-icons {
   0% {
      font-size: 0;
   }

   100% {
      font-size: 3.5em;
   }
}   


.caja{
   -webkit-animation-name: caja;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
   /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1 ;*/
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;/*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */
    border-color: var(--base);
    background-color: var(--base);

} 



const images = document.querySelectorAll('.revealOnScroll');

observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      entry.target.classList.add('animated');
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove('animated');
    }

  });
});

images.forEach(image => {
  observer.observe(image);
});
```